# What's the difference: We had hoped 'to live/to be living' in our new house by now...

Tags: verbs, gerunds, complements, progressive-aspect

> We had hoped **to live/to be living** in our new house by now, but the builders are still working on it.

***UPDATED***:  I mean what is semantically the difference between **to live** and **to be living** there?

Why  don't we use *living* or just *to live* there instead?

What is more, would you show me a resource for using such a structure – bold part?

Comment: Both **hope** + ***that-clause*** as well as **hope + to + verb-infinitive** is possible. Also **hope + for + something** is possible. Please consult a good dictionary and a usage dictionary. I used http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hope_1 to check the usage of **hope**.

Comment: **to be living/to live** is possible. But **to be live** is ungrammatical. **living** is an adjective in **to be living**, while **to live** is an infinitive construction.

Comment: To those who have been engaged in an edit war, please desist. The moderation team would rather see this question get answered than locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We had hoped **to be living** in our new house by now, but the builders are still working on it.
>   (Why don't we use living or just to live there instead?)

The verb **to hope** uses the particle **to** when it connects to another verb in the infinitive form:

> I hoped **to** play. (Not "I hoped play")

In other words, it takes an "infinitive complement". That's why you need that **to**.

**Be living** uses the so-called [*continuous* or *progressive* aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_progressive_aspects#English). This aspect is created by using [BE + Present Participle]: [*be + liv**ing***]. So you need that **be**.

The progressive aspect is used for actions that are ongoing at the time in question. The moment in time mentioned in your sentence is "by now". So, the meaning is "We had hoped that by this moment in time, we would **be living** in our new house".

Why not "live"? The phrase "by now" invites the use of a "[dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_verb)" verb, a verb that expresses an action. When we use the simple form "live", it denotes a more permanent, long-lasting situation. In other words, the verb "live" acts like a "*[stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb)*":

> I hoped **to live**. (very "stative": I hoped to be in the *state* of being alive)
>   I hoped **to live** in a castle. (less "stative")
>   I hoped **to be living** in a castle by January 1, 2015. (more "dynamic")

Comment: Nice explanation considering the aspect of transition. And also why not "to live". +!

Comment: @Man_From_India - thank you! But I'm not sure whether it would be really wrong to use "to live" there. It's classed among dynamic verbs, according to my googling.. I'll wait for a native speaker's opinion.

Comment: hmm that's true. Let's wait for them. But logically we should not here use "to live", only because of "by now". That is exactly what you said, and I second that.

Comment: Is there any situation we could use "to live by now"?

Comment: We're waiting for native speakers.

Comment: I am a native speaker. *To be living* is correct. The explanation above is clear, complete, and correct.

Comment: You need to note that **progressive aspect** is usually and more often than not used to indicate future action. Using **by now** seems to support my explanation.

Comment: Why does the phrase *by now* invite the use of a dynamic verb? I don't suppose there can be more of a stative verb than *to be*, yet *We had hoped to be in our new house by now* is as felicitous as it gets.

Comment: The answer has nothing to do with whether *live* is stative or not. *Live* is dynamic in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> I had hoped **to be living** in our new house by now.

The sentence is approximately equivalent to "I had hoped that we would have been fully moved in, unpacked, and settled into the new house by now."

The ongoing aspect suggests  the normalcy of a day-to-day routine.

> Are you living in your new house yet?
>   --Hardly. We're moved in, but we've only unpacked the necessities and have plenty of work ahead of us before we're fully settled in.
>
> What's your oldest child up to these days?
>   --She's married now, and living in Texas.

The implication is that she moved to Texas long enough ago to be settled into her new life there.

Comment: The question, as edited, is also concerned with the use of **to live** in the same sentence, whether it is valid in the sentence, and what is the difference between it and *to be living*.

Comment: Have at it, then, my friend. Have at it.

Comment: So you won't proffer an opinion as to the felicity of *to live* in the sentence?

Comment: I don't have the time to justify the answer I would give, which is that "We had hoped *to live* in our new house *by now*" is marginally grammatical/ungrammatical.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I wonder how many native speakers would say "I had hoped to be living...".

Comment: @Rathony:  I would think a decent plurality, but not a majority. I'm referring to the past perfect.   A majority would say "to be living", because "I had hope *to live* in our new house *by now*" is not quite grammatical.

Comment: @Rathony: there's nothing special about that sentence. It's idiomatic and hardly uncommon. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hoped%20to%20be%20living%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: **to be living** is quite popular and you're very wrong.

Comment: @TRomano what about the parallel *I had hoped to kick his ass by now*? Seems felicitous.

Comment: @Rathony: The past perfect is hardly rare, though perhaps one could say that the less educated the person, the less likely they are to use it. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+I+had+hoped%2Cas+I+hoped&year_start=1985&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20I%20had%20hoped%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20I%20hoped%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Alan Carnack: The prepositional phrase **by now** refers to a span of time that culminates with the present moment. Coupled with the past perfect, *I had hoped.... by now*, it refers on the semantic level to an action that has not been initiated or completed, to a hope that has not materialized, and so the verb must support the sense of has-been-initiated or has-been-completed. We find neither sense in the infinitive "to live" in *I had hoped **to live** in the new house by now.*  By contrast...

Comment: ... the verb phrase "kick his ass" is understood to mean "to defeat soundly", which *does* convey the idea of completion. You do not defeat someone until you have defeated them.  The speaker's sense of the verb's meaning in regard to actions initiated and actions completed determines whether the past perfect with "by now" will sound OK or odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the to-infinitive to live or to be + -ing form (to be living) after the verb hope, with a little difference in meaning.

You can use the to-infinitive to imply that you had hoped you would live in your new house by this time (the time of your speaking), of course; you didn't start living).  On the other hand, the usage of to be living 
Implies that you had hoped that you would be living in your new house by this time; it indicates the action of living already in progress.

So the use of the to-infinitive or to be (infinitive) + the -ing form of the verb depends on whether you convey the sense of the action that would happen or that would be already happening.

Comment: Helpful. Useful. Thanks for addressing both infinitives, which the OP has made clear is his/her main concern (and which is why I started the bounty). I can't give an upvote just yet as, native speaker that I am, I'm still ruminating on whether *to live* is grammatical here, or at least idiomatic. It still sounds a bit off.

Comment: Alan Carmack, I appreciate your comments.